# PHP: fopen doesnt seems to work after using filesize()?

Tags: php, fopen, filesize

PHP help needed for the beginner here.
I am trying to write(or append) some string to empty .txt file with if statement. 
And then also opening the file but it fails due to 0 length issue.

```
$filename = 'sometext.txt';  //empty text file
$size = filesize($filename);
if( $size <= 0 ) {
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'a');
    fwrite($handle, 'blah blah blah...');
    fclose($handle);
}

$handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
$current = fread($handle,filesize($filename));
```

This wont let me write or append to `$filename`. 
But if I comment out if statement, then it works.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Why would you check the file size? Do a `print_r($size)` to see what's the size of the file, even if it's empty.

Comment: provide a `var_dump($size)` after `$size = filesize($filename);`

Comment: Thanx for the quick response. At first visit, I get `Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0`. But I reload the page error's gone and `sometext.txt` is filled with text `blah blah blah...`.

Comment: I guess I get Warning message because I try to re-open('r') soon after appending(or writing). So PHP seems to get the text file that's before filled with blah blah string...

Comment: If I put `echo 'gets here.';` in this if statement, this code outputs `gets here`. So it does go inside the if statement but doesn't do `fopen write or append` job it seems... I am really confused.

Comment: `clearstatecache` was solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you open the file in append mode, if you know, the file doesn't contain something?
You should also change your fwrite line, because you use the wrong handle

```
$filename = 'sometext.txt';  //empty text file
$size = filesize($filename);
if( $size <= 0 ) {
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
    fwrite($handle, 'blah blah blah...');
    fclose($handle);
}

$handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
$current = fread($handle,filesize($filename));
```

If you want to append something to an existing file, you have to change your compare statement to `>=`

Comment: @Phillip Thanks I did try using `'w'` but I still gets `fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0` message.

Comment: @norixxx the results of filesize are cached... so you have to use `clearstatecache`. But why not simply use `file_get_contents` to read the whole file?

Comment: your `clearstatcache` suggestion did work for my problem. I put `clearstatcache` after appeding and before re-fopening('r') the text file.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking if the filesize is `<` or = `0`. If the filesize is for example 1 Byte, you will never reach the fopen/fwrite/fclose calls in your if-section.

If you comment `$size = filesize($filename)` out, $size is not defined. In PHP not defined and 0 are equal and you reach the if-section. That's why it works then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$my_file = 'emptytxt.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'a') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$size = filesize($my_file);
$data = 'New data line 1';
if($size <= 0)
{
fwrite($handle, $data);
}
fclose($handle);
```